# Cross Platform Coloured text in C

Tags: c, colors, console

I was wondering how you could print coloured text in a cross platform manner in C. I have looked at all the other answers on the forum, but none of them work during my testing (on Windows). For C++, I have the working code in **Fig 1**, however when converting the code to C and assigning the strings to a variable I get the error `\u001b is not a valid universal character` (**Fig 2**).

**Fig 1**

```cpp
namespace Fore {
    const std::string BLACK = "\u001b[30m";
    // Rest of code is not included since it is just a repetition of the above code with background and style ANSI codes as well.
```

**Fig 2**

[Image here since I don't have enough reputation to embed images yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXsfi.png)

Comment: There is no cross-platform way.  But the most common way, likely to work in many places (perhaps even most, but certainly not all) is `printf("\033[%dm", color_index)`.

Comment: Why does the C++ code work on all systems then (except for the old Windows terminal)? What is preventing me from writing the same escape sequences in C?

Comment: Um, because it's old?

Comment: I think your problem is that `\u001b` is an excessively modern way of writing the ESC character.  Try `\033`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! If you want to, you can post the comment as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer. As well as making that change, I also had to run the compiled exe out of CLion (my IDE) since it still uses the old Windows terminal.

Comment: @SteveSummit: It's not "excessively modern". It's explicitly forbidden by 6.4.3/2 (in C; in C++, UCNs for control characters are fine).

Comment: Please, don't tag your question as `C` if your code is `C++` specific.  C and C++ are interoperable but very different languages.

Comment: @LuisColorado I was just wondering how to convert the code into C without any errors.

Comment: @splewdge. but your question doesn't talk about code conversion, you ask how to do things in C, but show C++ code.  If you want good advice, you need to make the effort to give us good explanation about your problem.  Try to focus on the problem you try to solve and don't mix unrelated things, that only confound the people and make difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C and C++ have different rules for "universal character names" (UCNs), which is the official name for `\u` and `\U` sequences. (They're not the same as "escape sequences" because UCNs can be used outside quoted literals, for example in identifier names.)

In C, the rule is:

> A universal character name shall not designate a code point where the hexadecimal value is:
>
> - less than 00A0 other than 0024 (`$`), 0040 (`@`), or 0060 (`` ` ``);
> - in the range D800 through DFFF inclusive; or
> - greater than 10FFFF82)

So in C, you can't use UCNs for control characters, which is what the error message is telling you.

C++ is more generous; it allows you to use UCNs for control characters and other characters with small codepoints, but only inside string and character literals. (C++ also prohibits surrogate codepoints and excessively large codes, the second and third points in the above list.)

Both C and C++ allow you to use octal escape sequences (`\033`) or hexadecimal escapes sequences (`\x1B`). I'd personally recommend the latter, but `\033` is common because hexadecimal escapes were not in the very earliest versions of C, and so `\033` became a common idiom.

None of this is really platform-independent. Lots of platforms have consoles which don't interpret ANSI style codes.

Answer (score 0):

The way `\uxxxx` sequences are interpreted by the compiler as input source text, before the text is tokenized.  You have included a control character (not a compiler escape sequence) inside a string literal (like you had keyed it literally, in the string).  Just change the control character by an escape sequence, as in:

```
    const std::string BLACK = "\x1b[30m";
```

or, more portably (the octal representation is included in the first C compilers, while the `\xAB` notation was introduced with ANSI-C):

```
    const std::string BLACK = "\033[30m";
```

both sequences indicate to the compiler that you want to put the equivalent character in the compiler output, but they are four character sequences, not a single one.  And both work in C/C++.

BTW, a portable way to do coloured output is to use a library like termcap (part of curses) that determines the terminal type from the running environment, and so, selects the appropiate sequence for the used terminal.  Look at the manual pages for termcap (curs_termpcap(3X)) for info about the termcap library.  If you need more advanced functions (like cursor addressing or windows) then the full ncurses library should be the option.  This library was developed when the `vi` editor was born, in an age in which the amount of terminals of different classes and control languages was in use.